# Jest React - how to target a specific item in List and then to simulate click event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a list `<List>` and each `<ListItem>` will have a unique class which later on will be used for simulate click event.

```
<List>
   <ListItem
     className={'list-item-foo'}
     button
     onClick={() => this.handleEventToUpdateState('foo')}
   >
      <ListItemText inset primary='foo' />
   </ListItem>

   <ListItem className={'list-item-bar} button onClick={() => this.handleEventToUpdateState('bar')}>
      <ListItemText inset primary='bar' />
   </ListItem>
</List>
```

In React Test

```
component.find('ListItem.list-item-foo').simulate('click');
```

However, it seems like the event handler is not triggered at all.

Could you please kindly to explain to how target the element and trigger the event?